# How do I insert values in an idenity column over a linkedServer

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, linked-server

I wrote a stored procedure on Microsoft SQL Server 2008. This SP lives/executed on Server1 (source). This SP will insert records into Server2 (destination) "a remote server." However, the source server will have value in the column "ID" which is an identity column. Since the source table have value for the "ID" column, I need to carry the same value over to the destination and NOT let the destination server generate a new value.

To make sure the destination server won't have conflict when inserting data, I must do the following steps

1. Start Transaction
2. Truncate the table on the destination table
3. Turn on IDENTITY_INSERT on the destination table while executing the SP on the source server i.e. Server1
4. Insert the records from the source table to the destination
5. Finally turn off IDENTITY_INSERT on the destination table
6. Commit the transaction

Now, since I can't truncate or set the IDENTITY_INSERT flag for the destination table from the source. I have to use [sp_executesql](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) to get the job done.

Here is what I have done so far

```
-- this is important to execute transaction over linked servers
SET XACT_ABORT ON; 

BEGIN TRANSACTION;

-- Truncate the destination "remote" table
EXECUTE [Server1].[db1].[dbo].sp_executesql "TRUNCATE TABLE [SurveysEngine].[dbo].[surveys]"; 

-- Turn on IDENTITY_INSERT on the destination "remote" table
EXECUTE [Server1].[db1].[dbo].sp_executesql "SET IDENTITY_INSERT [SurveysEngine].[dbo].[surveys] ON"; 

-- Copy the data from the soruce "local" to the destonation "remote"
INSERT INTO [Server1].[db1].[dbo].[surveys]([id],[name],[client_id],[status],[created_at],[updated_at]) 
SELECT [id],[name],[client_id],[status],[created_at],[updated_at]
FROM [surveys]; 

-- Turn on IDENTITY_INSERT off the destination "remote" table
EXECUTE [Server1].[db1].[dbo].sp_executesql "SET IDENTITY_INSERT [SurveysEngine].[dbo].[surveys] OFF"; 

COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

Howerver, when I execute the SP I get the following error

> Msg 7344, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>   The OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11"
>   for linked server "Server1" could not INSERT INTO table
>   "[Server1].[db1].[dbo].[surveys]" because of column "id". The user did
>   not have permission to write to the column.

The use I am using to connect to the destination table belongs to `sysadmin` security group.

Is my issue really permission? Or, does executesql not work in a transaction making `SET IDENTITY_INSERT [SurveysEngine].[dbo].[surveys] ON` not to have any affect which is why I am unable to insert the value?

I do believe the issue is due to permission. If it was due to IDENTITY_INSERT not being set I would get error like this

```
Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'table' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.
```

If the issue is indeed permission related, what other permission do I need to set for the use in order to write to the identity column?

Comment: If you are just transferring data from source to destination server, why not remove the identity property on the destination table? If you leave it there you are not guaranteed that the value is already in use, if it is what happens then?

Comment: @mheptinstall I need to keep the identity on both servers. To make sure there is no conflict I first truncate the destination table.

Comment: Why do you need identity in the destination at all?

Comment: Truncating the destination, inserting and then turning identity back on doesn't sound right, regardless I think you need to check that the IDENTITY_INSERT ON statement is being executed correctly http://www.trycatchfinally.net/2013/04/write-permission-error-when-inserting-over-linked-server/

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri I want to copy source to destination, make changes (insert/update/delete) records. then push the changes made on detestation back to the source. It is a way to stage and test new changes to to a database before it is published to production.

Comment: Not clear with procezses. What do yoy mean by push bac?

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri by bush back I mean insert new records and update existing. basically I want to copy the data in production into a staging database. Make my changes, and test them out. Finally copy the new changes from staging to production.

Comment: So remove identity prop from dest and make it nullable. Insert from source. Then push back: update with join, insert when id is null in dest.